# How to peform sudo commands in a slurm-cluster when you are not an admin

Tags: python, cluster-computing, sudo

**Why I need sudo:**

I need to peform a sudo command in order to resolve an issue with installing a python package on my user account in a slurm cluster.

**What I tried:**

I do not have administrator rights for this cluster, so I created a virtual enviroment using "virtualenv". When I tried to peform the sudo command inside the virtual enviroment, I got asked to type my password, which I did, and got the message "*my_user_name is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported*".

Shouldn't I have full access inside the virtualenv I created? Typing "which python" in the terminal confirms that I'm in the virtual enviroment.

**What do you do, when you need to use sudo in slurm, and you are not an admin?**

**EDIT (including my error code when trying to install torch):**

```
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-bj95am_3/torch/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(README)
    RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

    Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bj95am_3/torch/
```

Comment: If you're not an admin (or in the sudoers file anyway), you can't use sudo. What's the actual issue you're trying to resolve? Using sudo is probably the wrong answer.

Comment: If you don't have enough rights, creating virtual environments won't magically give them to you. Otherwise, it would've been a major security flaw.

Comment: I got an error when trying to install torch. Searching the error in google led me to a github thread where the best suggestion is to use "sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev".

Comment: Torch will not need libmysqlclient-dev, I'm fairly positive. Please edit in the actual error you're getting into your question.

Comment: This is my first time working with slurm, is it common practice to install all the python packages in your script one by one using pip?

Comment: @AKX I have included the error in the edit.

Comment: The common practice for managing package dependencies is to have a file named "requirements.txt" that lists all the packages that your app needs.  Then you can make sure that all of the packages listed in that file are installed by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: @Hako Did you read the error and follow the link in it? :D

Comment: @AKX I did try the miniconda approach yesterday (and other approaches..I have spend way too long trying to get my scipt.sh to run), but I ended in a loop of errors that all seemed to need sudo. It seems that it just comes down to my lack of knowledge. I will take a break and try the requirements.txt approach. Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` is a Linux system tool that has nothing to do with Python.  It allows you to act as the root user (or some other user) on the machine you are on.  If you haven't been provided with that right, there's nothing you can do to change that.

Creating a `virtualenv`, something you're doing in your own Linux account, won't magically provide you the ability to perform actions with `sudo` that require root privileges.  The neat thing about a `virtualenv` is that when you make changes to that environment, they all happen locally to your user account.  So you can install Python packages yourself, where to affect the global Python installation on the machine, you'd need `sudo` privileges, and so you wouldn't be able to do that.

You can't do:

> apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev

because that installs a package in the global environment of the Linux system you are on.  This is why you have to use `sudo`.  If you don't have `sudo` rights, you'll have to have an administrator do this for you.